# Webscraping in R over multiple pages & levels, How to fix the error: 'url does not exist'?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape some data from [the dutch train disruptions website](https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/storingen?lines=&reasons=&date_before=31-12-2018&date_after=01-01-2018&page=1). I have done this successfully before with multiple pages, but I am now trying to go a level deeper. But unfortunately I am getting the following error:

`Error: '/storingen/25215-29-december-2018-defect-spoor-amersfoort-ede-wageningen' does not exist.`

This should be the correct url but I think it missing the first part

`https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/storingen/25235-31-december-2018-seinstoring-groningen-eemshaven`

I can't seem to locate the origin of the problem. I think i might be possible that not the entire url is retrieved.

#### I am using the following script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_element_data <- function(link){  
  if(!is.na(link)){
    html <- read_html(link)
    Sys.sleep(2)
    datum <- html %>%
      html_node(".disruption-cause") %>%
      html_text()
    return(tibble(datum=datum))
  }
}

get_elements_from_url <- function(url){
  html_page <- read_html(url)
  Sys.sleep(2)
  route <- scrape_css(".disruption-line",".resolved",html_page)
  problem <- scrape_css("em",".resolved",html_page)
  time <- scrape_css(".timestamp",".resolved",html_page)
  element_urls <- scrape_css_attr(".resolved","div","href",html_page)
  element_data_detail <- element_urls %>%
    map(get_element_data) %>%
    bind_rows()
  elements_data <- tibble(route=route, problem=problem, time=time, element_urls=element_urls)
  elements_data_overview <- elements_data[complete.cases(elements_data[,2]), ]
  return(bind_cols(elements_data_overview,element_data_detail))
}

scrape_write_table <- function(url){
  list_of_pages <- str_c(url, 2)
  list_of_pages %>%
    map(get_elements_from_url) %>%
    bind_rows()
}

trainDisruptions <- scrape_write_table("https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl/storingen?lines=&reasons=&date_before=31-12-2018&date_after=01-01-2018&page=")

View(trainDisruptions)
```

Comment: Websites often store internal links without the root domain, so you will need to paste the `https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl` back in

Comment: @AndrewGustar Yes thank you, the HTML is indeed missing the root domain. What is the best way to add this in? (Where in the code?)

I tried it with the paste0 function. It works in a simple set-up like down below but it doesn't work inside of the script.  

`path <- "/storingen/25215-29-december-2018-defect-spoor-amersfoort-ede-wageningen"
paste0("https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl", path)`

Comment: After you define `element_urls` in the second function, add a line `element_urls <- paste0("https://www.rijdendetreinen.nl", element_urls)` (assuming the output of `scrape_css_attr` is just a character vector)

Comment: @AndrewGustar Yes, I tried that but unfortunately it is still nog working. I am getting the error: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Could not resolve host: www.rijdendetreinen.nlNA` Is this related or is it a different problem?

Comment: No, that is because one of your links is coming back as an `NA`. Perhaps add `element_urls <- element_urls[!is.na(element_urls)]` before the paste statement.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewGustar that solved the problem!